# How to view and edit the code of a PDF file

Tags: pdf

I was wondering how to view and edit the code of a PDF file?

1. By viewing, I don't want to see the binary format, so I think `hexdump` may not be what I want. I tried `gedit`,
   but no encoding method can be used to decode the PDF content.
2. By editing, I would like to search for `/Fit` and change them to
   `/XYZ` by for example sed. But my command `sed s/\/Fit/\/XYZ/ < 1.pdf > 2.pdf` seem not change the appearance of my PDF as I expected,
   although it doesn't report any error. I was wondering if `sed` can
   actually work on PDF files as if they were plain text?

The context of my questions can be found from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/306803/zooming-size-of-pdf-files-and-bookmarks/307290#307290). My OS is Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `sed` with binary files (at least GNU sed; some implementations may have trouble with files containing null characters or not ending with a newline character). But the command you used only replaces the first occurrence of `/Fit` on each line, and lines are pretty much meaningless in a PDF file. You need to replace all occurrences:

```
 sed s/\/Fit/\/XYZ/g
```

It would be more robust only replace `/Fit` if it's not followed by a word constituent (e.g. not replacing `/Fitness`; I don't know if your file contains occurrences of `/Fit` that would cause trouble). Here's one way:

```
perl -pe 's!/Fit\b!/XYZ!g'
```

Comment: Thanks! It now works! (1) I was wondering how sed search characters in binary content? Does sed firstly encode the query characters before search? (2) In the last command, what does `!`, `\b` and `g` mean? Can it be done without perl just with sed?

Comment: @Tim (1) Sed loads the data into memory, operates on it and prints it out. Why would it need to encode anything? (2) `g` means to replace all occurrences on each line, in both sed and perl. `!` is the separator; you can choose (almost) any character as the separator for the `s` command (this goes both in sed and perl). `\b` means a word boundary; it exists in perl but not in sed.

Comment: About (1), because the characters that you give to sed in the command are human readable. If the content to search in is completely binary, how can sed find the query word there?

Comment: @Tim Text is binary data that happens to be human readable.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, regardless of whether a file in which sed searches is binary or text, it is always binary in memory. If the file to be searched in is not purely text, can the query word be specified as binary data to sed?

Comment: @Tim Yes, you can pass binary data in the query. You'll have to insert the characters literally in your sed or shell source code.

Comment: How is that different from specifying text to sed?

Comment: @Tim It isn't, that's the whole point. If you want to continue this, I suggest we move to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux).

Answer (score 39):

Regarding your 1st question ("viewing source code, but no binary"): there are a few options which you have in order to de-compress the internal binary streams which are attached to many objects.

My favorite tool for this is **[QPDF](http://qpdf.sf.net/)**, available on all major OS platforms. The following command ***de-compresses*** all streams and all object streams:

```
 qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable orig.pdf expanded.pdf
```

Now you can open your PDF in any text editor. (There may still be some binary blobs in there: for example, font files and ICC profiles, which wouldn't make sense for QPDF to expand).

To ***re-compress*** the `expanded.pdf` again after editing, you can run:

```
 qpdf expanded.pdf orig2.pdf
```

(Careful when manually editing PDFs! You need to know a lot about their internal syntax in order to do this right. As soon as you add or delete a single byte, you can get error messages from PDF readers who may no longer be able to open it, because the PDFs internal ToC is corrupted, which is based on byte-offset calculations. Just replacing `Fit` by `XYZ` strings should go fine, though...)

Comment: You can also add or remove text. When the length of an object stream changes the byte offsets can be recomputed by using the `fix-qdf` program that is part of qpdf. You still have to be a bit careful, though. See http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html#ref.qdf

Comment: @H.Rittich: Thx for the comment... In what way do you think does this open a new perspective on the problem? Did you think we don't know that we can add or remove text this way?

Comment: @KursPfeifle: I do not make any assumptions on what you know. The answer states that editing a PDF this way *needs* to preserve the byte offsets of the objects in the file. It is, however, possible to change the byte offsets when later correcting them by using `fix-qdf`. Hence, if you want to replace a string by a string of different length, it is possible, but you need to use the `fix-qdf` tool. I would say, that this is a useful addition to the answer.

Comment: @H.Rittich: Thx for giving your perspective. When I stressed the need to preserve byte offsets of objects I did not want to advice people about *HOW* they should do this. Had you worded your comment slightly differently, I would have understood the intention of your comment faster.

Answer (score 2):

Use LibreOffice or OpenOffice to open the PDF, view it, replace things, write a new PDF, etc.  I think that you can even use it from the command line or programmatically if there are a lot of documents to process.

Note that PDFs from *some* sources, e.g. Scanners, often contain the pages as images rather than as text so you will be out of luck with them for using search and replace.

Comment: (1/2) Be aware of the following fact: LibreOffice is not a native PDF editor. When it opens a PDF, it converts all pages to a vector image (which may keep the raster parts from the original PDF as raster parts) and opens it in the *LibreOffice* ***Draw*** part of the LibreOffice suite. Then, when it saves the edited PDF file, it will be a PDF file which was exported from the native LibreOffice Draw format (with the suffix *.odg*) to PDF.

Comment: (2/2) This workflow may have unexpected side effects. Moreover, the LibreOffice Draw application may not be able to correctly import all elements from the original PDF. However, in many cases it still may be a useful tool for all those folks who have no better means available.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is line-oriented, that makes it not well suited for binary files, which are structured as blocks not lines.
Try using bbe (bbe-.sourceforge.net) instead.

Alternatively, both Emacs (GNU and XEmacs) and vim open PDF files seamlessly.  It's not very pretty printed of course, as it is mixed text and binary, but it's sufficient for your editing purposes.
There is a [Pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) plugin for vim that makes everything easier, download [here](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/pdftk.vim.zip) (zip file).
As you probably know, both above editors have powerful search-and-replace capabilities.

Also, converting the PDF to [QDF mode](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html#ref.qdf) before makes editing PDF files really easy.

Comment: You may also try to edit with `sed` using the `-b` switch.  if it works I will add this to my answer.

Comment: @Tim: what do you mean by "does not show anything", just empty? any error message?  Also, can you try with XEmacs ? (all three of them worked for me).

Comment: Never mind about `-b`, it's cygwin specific.

Comment: Emacs says "File 1.pdf is large (9MB), really open? (y or n)". I chose "y", and then  nothing is there.

Comment: Most probably a Emacs problem, do you have XEmacs? (I just opened a 31 MB PDF without any problems).

Comment: (1) XEmacs works, thanks! So are Emacs and XEmacs different things? Is it that XEmacs can display mixture of readable characters and binary, while Emacs cannot? (2) In (X)Emacs, can the search and replace be done once for all, instead of one by each occurrence? (3) For bbe, is its website bbe-.sourceforge.net or bbe.sourceforge.net? The latter does not work either. What is it for?

Comment: (1) They have many differences, see [here](http://www.xemacs.org/About/XEmacsVsGNUemacs.html) and [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAndXEmacs), this topic is quite heated, so take everything with a grain of salt.  (2) Yes, when it asks the first time whether to replace enter '!' (exclamation mark).  (3) It's the first one, if you can't get to it just search "bbe" on SourceForge.

Comment: Thanks! (3) I looked at the cached page of bbe, but still wonder what bbe can do that sed cannot? I.e., what is the advantage of bbe?