# Non rendered pdf/raw pdf?

Tags: pdf

If you have an html-file you get two versions, a raw format with tags and warts or the rendered version.

What would be the equivalent in the case of pdf? How could you work with the raw form, for maybe change a word here and there?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17220/how-to-view-and-edit-the-code-of-a-pdf-file